# unable to connect to azure sql server from vsts

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to deploy test.dacpac file using vsts to azure sql server, Given connection details properly and it is getting connected if I try to connect it from visual studio.

But when it tries to deploy file using vsts, gets error message -

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while 
establishing a connection to SQL Server azure
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Note: There is no firewall rule applied, it has default settings, though the virtual machine on which VSTS agent is installed is in another Azure AD subscription.

Do I have to look into VPN for this?

Comment: How do you deploy database to azure sql server? Do you use [Azure SQL Database Deployment task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeployment/README.md)? What's the detail setting in Firewall section of Azure SQL Database Deployment task? Set system.debug to true and queue build, then share the log on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the FQDN for database name instead of the IP address. e.g. myAzureSQLDB.windows.database.net.

You need to configure Azure SQL Database firewall. Make sure "Allow access to Azure Services" is turned on. If that does not work, then try adding firewall rule 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255.